# Changing clock position in a powerdot slide template (\pddefinetemplate[slide]{slide})

Tags: templates, powerdot

I've created a slide template and tried changing the clock position like so:

```
\pddefinetemplate[slide]{slide}{
  textpos={.20\slidewidth,.75\slideheight},
  textwidth=.75\slidewidth,
  titlepos={.15\slidewidth,.85\slideheight},
  tocpos={.015\slidewidth,.75\slideheight},
  clockpos={.23\slidewidth,.08\slideheight}
}{\rput[bl](0,0){\includegraphics[width=\slidewidth, height=\slideheight]{fundo-slides.eps}}}
```

The idea was for it to go to the lower-left corner of my slide, over a specif piece of my background (set with the \rput command above).

The problem is that, instead of showing the clock, it only show a blue-ish field in that position, instead of showing the clock.

And to make things even weirder, sometimes the clock does show up, but if I recompile the document it goes away (even if no changes were made).

I've tried playing with clockcolor=black, and clockhook= several different positions, but nothing seems to fix it.

What else do I need to set on the template for the clock to show up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example making use of all available clock setting options provided by Powerdot. Some options go into `\pdsetup`, others into `\pddefinetemplate`.

The clock is moved to the bottom left corner of the slide (as requested):

```
\documentclass[clock]{powerdot}

\pdsetup{
  clockformat=yyyy/mm/dd h:MM tt, %do not show seconds
  clockrefresh=60000 %update every 60 seconds
}

\pddefinetemplate[slide]{slide}{
  clockpos={0.01\slidewidth,0.0},
  clockhook=bl, % anchor
  clockalign=0, % within clockwidth : 0=left, 1=centre, 2=right
  clockcolor=blue,
  clockcharsize=40pt,
  clockwidth=7cm,
  clockheight=30pt,
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alex, that plus your pdclock.sty you posted on https://github.com/agrahn/animate/issues/1#issuecomment-323094453 made it work. Thanks!

Comment: There is a new Powerdot version on its way into the distros via CTAN, making the patch on GitHub obsolete.